# Do we have a simple proof for this criterion for basepoint freeness?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, birational-geometry

The following is a criterion by Fujita ([On the structure of polarized varieties with $\Delta$-genera zero](https://repository.dl.itc.u-tokyo.ac.jp/record/39768/file_preview/jfs220106.pdf)).

> Consider a complex smooth projective variety $X$ of dimension $n$ and an ample divisor $H$, then Hilbert polynomial $P(m)=\chi(X,\mathcal{O}_X(mH))$ can be expanded to
> $$P(m)=\chi(X,\mathcal{O}_X)+\sum_{j=1}^n\chi_j(X,H)\frac{(m+0)\dotsm(m+j-1)}{j!}.$$
> Then
> $$\chi_n(X,\mathcal{O}_X(H))-h^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(H))+n=0$$
> implies that $H$ is basepoint free.

It is a special case of a general result evaluating the dimension of the base locus of $H$ for non-necessary smooth varieties. I wonder if we have a simple proof for this special statement.

Comment: Your formula for $P(m)$ seems to imply $P(0)=1$, which is obviously incorrect.

Comment: @abx It is a careless mistake, I have corrected it.